# Should Drupal 5 posts be closed?

Tags: discussion, voting-to-close

Since only [~0.1%](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/drupal) of Drupal sites are still using Drupal 5 and it's not supported since 2011, the questions and answers are outdated and probably not useful to anybody.

Can all Drupal [5](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5) be closed as outdated? Closed/locked as outdated for historical purposes. I don't think any new answers will provide any new benefits.

Most of them doesn't provide any benefits, because nobody uses Drupal 5, so the information is outdated and can only confuse people. The benefits include that it can prevent some spams.

Comment: I think I'd say not, personally - what benefit would closing these questions provide to the site?

Comment: A lot of old D5 questions are showing up in the review. I came here to see what to do with them. I guess I'll just "Skip".

Comment: I've flagged few of them which weren't on-topic or very low quality. E.g. like module recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question was tagged for Drupal 5 and answered correctly for Drupal 5, then it isn't outdated.  It just may not be helpful to a large number of people.  I see no harm in keeping these, and don't think it is beneficial to close or lock the ~30 questions we have about Drupal 5.

Answer (score 3):

Even if those questions were really outdated (which is not true, as MPD said), outdated questions are not closed, if they aren't off-topic.

The *historical reason* lock says: "This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question** for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here." It would imply that Drupal 5 questions are not on-topic, which is not true. Even if Drupal 5 is not supported anymore, questions about Drupal 5 are still on-topic, if they aren't off-topic for other reasons (e.g. because the question is asking to find or recommend a module).